# Rails 4 - manifest JS not available in AJAXed-in JS rendered partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asset-pipeline, render

Good evening SO,

I am having issues gaining access to javascript functions in manifest files when rendering a JS partial.  Below are the files which make the current articles#index page work:

**Manifested files:**

assets/javascripts/option_set_interface.js.coffee.erb

```
on_load = ->
  load_article_click_handlers $('ul.index li.article')

$(document).ready on_load                        //standard DOM refresh
document.addEventListener 'page:change', on_load //turbolinks

load_article_click_handlers = (jQuery_object) ->
  .. Do some stuff...
```

**load_article_click_handlers** is the function I would like to gain access to in create.js.erb

assets/javascript/articles.js.coffee

```
//= require option_set_interface
```

**articles_controller.rb:**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_path }
      format.js   { render 'create' }
    end
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  protected
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

**Views and partials:** views/articles/

index.html.haml

```
- provide(:title, 'Article list')

%h1 Article list

.row
  .aside.span3
    .row
      %ul.index
        - @articles.each do |article|
          = render article
      = render 'new'
```

_article.html.haml

```
%li.article
  %input{ type: 'hidden', value: article.id, name: 'article_id' }
  = article.id
  = article.title
```

_new.html.haml

```
= form_for Article.new, remote: true, html: { id: 'new_article_form' } do |f|
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary'
```

create.js.erb (where the issue is)

```
new_list_item = $('<%= escape_javascript( render @article ) %>')
new_list_item.prependTo('ul.index').slideDown()
load_article_click_handlers(new_list_item) //this is the line that breaks the code
```

The code works well, until I try to call load_article_click_handlers in create.js.erb.  I am not sure how to get debug information on it because it uses rails' magic ajax.  I'm not very sure how to capture the response.

create.js has access to jquery, clearly.  But it does not seem to accept my custom functions.  Any help or advice is appreciated, particularly tips on how to debug rail's ajax rendered JS.  Currently attemtping to access load_article_click_handlers causes teh script not to run at all.

*Things I have tried:*

Adding '//= require option_set_interface' to application.js
using javascript_inlude_tag 'option_set_interface' in create.js.erb

*EDIT*

Found 1 correction, did not eliminate problem.

Comment: The function `load_article_click_handlers` should be called.  Have you tried adding some debug message e.g. `console.log 'test'` inside that function to test if it's getting called from `create.js.erb`?

Comment: `load_article_click_handlers` is not getting called.  As soon as I reference it, the file is "successfully rendered" but my local server, but no javascript executes.  If I take out the reference to `load_article_click_handlers`, it runs fine otherwise.

Comment: Do you have `articles.js.coffee` loaded into the layout separately or added to the `application.js`?

Comment: Loaded separately with `= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller], "data-turbolinks-track" => true` in the application layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was going down the wrong path.  Issue was with coffeescript's anonymous function wrapper.  The feature was built to avoid "polluting the global namespace", which was exactly what I wanted to do with an include file.

Solution is to add

```
window.load_article_click_handlers = load_article_click_handlers
```

after the definition of load_article_click_handlers.

Hope this helps someone else.